# Using _exit() or exit() after spawn()?

Tags: c, exec, exit, spawn

As wikipedia states [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spawn_%28computing%29) : "Files that are open when a **spawn** call is made remain open in the child process". (quite similar to **exec()**)

OK, OS has kept some files opened & ready for our newly born unaware process. Assume that our process reamins unaware of those previously opened files and finally decides to terminate; while programming languages like C require some internal process clean up before termination.

my question is, **Does this kind of clean up affect those opened files in any way?** AFAIK they're not registered anywhere or with anything inside the process itself.

The answer should somehow define the programmer's behaviour while terminating the spawn()ed process(or even an exec()ed one). Can a full clean up procedure in any way hurt the parent? (for example by removing temporary files) and hence shouldn't the programmer use **_exit()** instead of **exit()**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **no**. The C runtime does not close file handles that are open at process exit, so you can exit from the parent process or the child process without worry about messing up the other.

The *kernel* is responsible for closing a file handle once there are no open references to it, which happens when the kernel destroys the process. And the kernel can handle this situation just fine.

Comment: @JSBangs: not 100%. What about temporary files? Upon program termination, they may get removed even though there exist another process IOing to that file.

Comment: @ned, `tmpfile` is not a problem. On *nix systems it's possible to write to a file that's been deleted--the handle to the deleted file remains open, and the file's inode isn't removed until the last handle is closed. On Windows, it's not possible to delete a file that has open handles, and the C library will take care of this condition by either marking tmp handles as non-temporary in the child process, or by simply ignoring errors encountered when attempting to close the file.

Comment: On *nix systems, `tmpfile` deletes the file as soon as it opens it. Or at least, I would hope it does on all real-world implementations.

Comment: WOW! these answers are correct, But I think we're ignoring the original question. what if I make my own OS that behaves differetly to *nix and Win? shouldn't C standard be covering that?

Comment: @ned, you can make a CrazyOS that does whatever you want. It's then up to the people that implement the C runtime for your OS to comply to the C standard.

Comment: @JSBangs, CrazyOS, I like that :D. ofc, this way what they implement is not fully standard compliance. Standard stricly says file is to be removed.